# What's itext 7 equivalent to getUnderContent in itext5?

Tags: itext, watermark, itext7

In itext5, we have used the getUnderContent and getOvercontent methods for the images respectively but in itext7, the image always coming over the PDF and can anyone tell us, how to change that getUnderContent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use #newContentStreamBefore

```
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.newContentStreamBefore(), pdfPage.getResources(), pdf);
```